# apache2 wont start

Tags: apache2, restart

I had my server up and running fine until my laptop got unplugged and died while i was away. now when i try to restart apache2 using `sudo apache2 -k restart' i get this error:

```
[Wed Aug 27 20:16:27.504121 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6953] AH00111: Config variable
${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Wed Aug 27 20:16:27.504212 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6953] AH00111: Config variable
${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Wed Aug 27 20:16:27.504240 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6953] AH00111: Config variable
${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Wed Aug 27 20:16:27.504255 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6953] AH00111: Config variable
${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Wed Aug 27 20:16:27.504277 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6953] AH00111: Config variable
${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Wed Aug 27 20:16:27.507253 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6953:tid 3074841216] AH00111:
Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Wed Aug 27 20:16:27.507466 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6953:tid 3074841216] AH00111:
Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Wed Aug 27 20:16:27.507491 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6953:tid 3074841216] AH00111:
Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

I didnt change anything to cause all this as it worked fine with no errors until i noticed one day that my server wasnt live. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled apache2 which did reinstall the apache2.conf file that gives the error, seeing as the stuff that i have added to the file are gone and the error changed from line 80 to line 74 but is the same error.

Comment: Do you have the file "envvars" in that directory?  If so, does it define ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} and ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}?

Comment: i have `export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2$SUFFIX` and `export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2$SUFFIX` in the envvars file. idk what any of this means how would i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your restart command, and got more or less the same errors; but apache is running normally, before and after that command.

It's been a while since I've done any website work, and I've forgotten much of what I knew.  But that is not the command I used to restart the server.  In fact, my notes specify that it never worked.

I used:

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

This may also work:

`sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: yea that explains the error, but not why my server isnt working via www. Ty

Comment: @ErikStagg - I guessed you asked the wrong question. I suggest asking the real question, telling us what happens and what you've done.  Did you get any error restarting the server?  If the server is running, then the problem is probably just configuration

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i had a couple problems and figured I would go one problem at a time. since my last post I figured out that i was having a problem with my dynamic DNS service and I think i have solved the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hopefully, you learned a little about troubleshooting.  It's always best to reduce problems to the basics, and confirm the basics before moving out to the more complex parts - in this case, making sure the site works for localhost.  Glad you got it under control.